# Will the Norway have no deadline to call family members to uk?

Tags: immigration, uk-visa, norway, pakistani-citizen

I am unable to find the qouted text from UK GOV website about Norway and UK after brexit.
I have heard Norwegians will be able to call family members after brexit in case the relationship existed before Brexit. Can someone clarify ?

Comment: Kindly clarify what you mean with 'call'. A country does not call anybody and phones will still work after the transition period. So it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Why would the deadline for Norway differ from the rest of the EU/EEA?

Comment: Perhaps because Norway is not a member of the EU, and because the UK's EEA affiliation continues until 31 Dec 2020.

Comment: I think Norwegians can still call people after brexit date ; if the relationship existed before the brexit

Comment: @MarkJohnson I suspect the OP is using it in the British sense of visit.

Comment: @Eric If that is the case, I don't thing anyone, on any side, intends to restrict short term visits in any way.